# AngularJS Twitter bootstrap 3 Navtab class removed

Tags: css, angularjs, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to add some extra styling to the bootstrap tabs dynamically via angularjs (computed values) however I Found that the class reference to the angular scope 'class="{{IsComplete1}}"' was removed. these computed values do display what is expected when not part of a class

What is the right way to add a class to a nav-tab dynamically?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="{{IsComplete1()}}"><a href="#Welcome" data-toggle="tab">Welcome</a></li>
      <li class="{{IsComplete2()}}"><a href="#Step1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a></li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was this was a bootstrap issue but it was just a simple angularjs issue

All I needed to do was use the ng-class directive i.e. `ng-class="IsComplete1()".`